# Specifying vertex position via coordinates in python graph-tool

Tags: python, graph-tool

Is it possible to plot a vertex at a particular position on the xy-axis by specifying coordinates? I want to have a square lattice of vertices without the edges between them (and then add edges later as I see fit).

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you have a graph called "g".

First create a property map by typing:

```
position = g.new_vertex_property("vector<double>")
```

You can manually add the coordinates of each vertex. For example if you want vertex 5 to be a position (2.5, -1.9) type:

```
position[g.vertex(5)] = (2.5, -1.9)
```

(Remember that vertices start at 0 in graph-tool)

To plot the graph, do:

```
graph_draw(g, pos=position)
```